# File download involving HTTP Basic Authentication

Tags: java

In my Java program i want to download a file from a server that uses Http Basic Authentication. Can i use the URL class of java.net package for this purpose ?.If not,which java class should i use ?

Please Help
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Highly recommend [Apache HTTP Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can:

```
final URL url = new URL(...);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();


if (username != null && username.trim().length() > 0 && password != null && password.trim().length() > 0) {
    final String authString = username + ":" + password;
    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encodeBase64(authString.getBytes()));
}

conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
conn.setDoInput(false);
conn.setDoOutput(true);

final OutputStream outs = conn.getOutputStream();

...

outs.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

finally, I solved the problem using this function:

```
    public void download(String url, String outPath, String authBase64) throws IOException {

    URL server = new URL(url); 

    URLConnection connection = (URLConnection) server.openConnection();

    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authBase64);
    connection.connect();
    InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(outPath));

    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int n = 0;
    while (-1 != (n = is.read(buffer))) {
        fos.write(buffer, 0, n);
    }

    is.close();
    fos.close();    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me, for retrieving a report from Stripe in October of 2020.  But it uses apache-commons-io 2.8.0 and java 11.

```
      private java.io.File downloadCsvReport(final java.net.URI https) throws IOException {
    
        java.io.File output = new java.io.File("report.csv");
    
        java.net.URL url = https.toURL();
        javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection secure = (javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        secure.setAuthenticator(new Authenticator() {
          protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(un, pw.toCharArray());
          }
        });
        secure.connect();
        try (InputStream inputStream = secure.getInputStream()) {
          org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(inputStream, output);
        } // auto closes inputStream
        return output; // no cleanup
      }
```

Comment: I am getting java.io.FileNotFoundException: <link>, then I click on the link and it is there. So I must be having some kind of authentication problem. The error originates from here: InputStream inputStream = secure.getInputStream()

Comment: Yeah, the uri that gets passed into this method is provided by Stripe, in this example.  Not sure how familiar you are with Stripe reports but it kinda goes like this, ... you tell Stripe what report you want and the date range.  Then Stripe gives you an instance id.  Then you use the instance id to poll for a status.  When the status is complete then Stripe will give you a URI to retrieve the completed report.  All of this is well outside the scope of the original question posted above.